# Why does some software not update itself?

Tags: windows, updates

I would like to know why some software doesn't have an update option?
Programs like for example "Steelseries Engine", "HwInfo", "VirtualBox" do not update themselves. When they notify me about a new version, I have to visit the homepage and download the new version and install it. Why can these programs not just update themselves like others do?
And secondly: If I have to download and install a new version by myself, is it ok to install the new version without uninstalling the old version?

Comment: Because the developers decided to keep things simple and not include built-in updating.

Comment: Probably because making sure that the correct thing being downloaded and installed is a job best left to the meat sitting in the chair. There have been a few news stories recently where automatic updaters have been vulnerable to man in the middle attacks because they failed to securely verify that what they were downloading was what they actually meant to download.

Comment: Because the software must support updating itself in order for it to update itself

Comment: It has happened far too many times lately that fix packs screwed things up before user could even say stop. And those user got very angry when the damage was done. I wonder how come that any software dares to be self-updating nowadays. Seems too reckless to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some (most) developers who make apps don't really feel that auto updating is required. It takes too much effort and even in some cases may not be possible.

Secondly it is fine to update your application without removing the old one. Most developers have made it so everything will work as usual including all your preferences saved. If you need to uninstall the application first it should tell you when you try but if not then just keep clicking next

*Next time please include OS (Windows 7, Windows 8, OSX)* :)

Comment: Just to add - some software it is NOT a good idea to update to the latest version without testing - especially if you are using software in corporate environment. So yes a manual update forces the user/IT person to check the "change log" and what it will change, what impact it may have, and if everything is "for the better" - then do the actual update.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons I can think of off the top of my head:

- Complexity. Auto updating sounds great, but it is not as simple as simple as you might think. Programs can be very complex and have lots of components under the hood. Sure, for a simple program it might be easy, but for a complex program such as VirtualBox there are software and hardware considerations. One has to make sure all the updated components work with each other. Not to mention complex version control and testing. Sometimes the simplest solution to updating is simply to exit the program, download, then install. In addition to that, the developers would most likely want to focus on actual program features rather then constantly testing the auto updater.
- Maintaining different versions. In some cases, you might want to have multiple versions of a program. If that is the case, you do not want to overwrite the old version. If you are a gamer. You might find you have many versions of DirectX installed. This allows game developers to use a specific version of DirectX they know is compatible with their game, without having to test newer versions. Java is another example. It is not uncommon for older Java applications to be incompatible with newer versions and vise versa.
- Cost. If you are going to maintain an update server(s), then there are costs involved. It has to be available, maintained, bandwidth has to be paid. In many cases, developers might not even have their own servers and the installers are downloaded from 3rd party websites.